Cannot connect to remote MySQL server via connection string
I have a server running at let’s say 10.55.1.95 that runs MySQL database engine. I try connecting to it on a different server lets say 10.55.1.98 via a connection string like
sql_alchemy_conn=mysql+mysqldb://my_user:password@10.50.1.95/my_db but I get an error saying access denied for user my_user@10.55.1.98. I can connect perfectly to the database via command line MySQL -u my_user -p -h 10.55.1.95 -P 3306 my_db. How do. I solve this connection string issue? I have the my_user setup to allow all hosts %
I also have a password that contains special characters like 1@??ZNbhg. I am using mysqlconnector

You either got the user name / password in the code incorrectly or they contain special characters ha make he connection string invalid, like @

Yes the password has special characters. How do I format the connection string. Let’s say the password is 1@??ZNbhg. What should be the correct connection string. I am using mysqlconnector.

Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

please check out the answers to the duplicate question.

Give the permissions:
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON my_db.* TO 'my_user'@'10.55.1.98' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

Test with Command Line Again with properly connecting:
mysql -u my_user -p -h 10.55.1.95 -P 3306 my_db


Already done this. It doesn’t work.

if the OP can connect to mysql from command line, then the problem can't be with access rights.

@Kenart,  Could you please verify the mysql credentials once?

I restarted the MySQL service and everything started working fine.
